# Magento product Issue

Tags: magento, product

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magento products will not show in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category)

I am adding products in magento from IMport facility and I add them successfully in backend but they are not visible in frontend.
Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem??
I did everything change some values in that product or some stuff like this.
Can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure those products;

- are assigned to a website
- are set to in stock and have a quantity (or disable stock)
- are enabled