# Products from category x not being displayed

Tags: magento

Here's the situation: I have a store with about 6 categories and some of those categories have sub-categories as well. In order to only display categories from a specific product on a specific page, I've created pages for each category and assigned a widget to display only categories from the category I've assigned it to.

However, instead of displaying the category it's supposed to, it gives me the following error:
`There are no products matching the selection.`

Anyone know what might be causing this? Because if I set the category to 0, it will display all of the products from every category...

You can see the problem I'm having here: http://store.qualitydishware.com/bowls

Thanks in advance guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by making sure all of the points in this question have been checked: [Magento products will not show in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category)

For me, i had to refresh the cache and reindex the website.