# Magento how to display products under root category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to display products under Magento "Default Category" ? Is there some kind of URL to do that.

I tried URL rewrite and got a url like "default-category.html", but it displays a 404 error page. I did the "Index Management" too. But, that didn't help either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks And Regards,
Rupak Banerjee.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

see the url

[Magento products will not show in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category)

The checklist for whether items are in stock follows. Some will seem stupid until the first time you spend an hour trying to figure this problem out:

- The products must be Visible in Catalog.
- The products must be Enabled.
- Product must have a stock Quantity.
- The product must be set to In Stock.
- If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
- The product must be assigned to the target Category.
- If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
- You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

Welcome to Magento. Hope that helps!

**Please let me know if not working.**

Comment: Nope. Mode re-write is enabled. But, it's still not working. All other pages work.

Comment: I have update my answer please take a look. see url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category

Comment: My question was it doesn't show in root category. For other categories it works well.