# Products missing from category view(only) in Magento after multistore .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, magento

I'm in the process of adding an additional website/storefront to an already active Magento website.

While setting this up on the development site, I noticed that whenever I drop in the .htaccess code for multistore all products disappear from the category views. however, I can still get to the produscts via direct link e.g. my-domain.com/category/product.

Here is the .htaccess code I'm using:

```
## Storefronts

# Main Store
SetEnvIf Host www\.my-domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=main-store_code
SetEnvIf Host www\.my-domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^my-domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=main-store_code
SetEnvIf Host ^my-domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

# Second Store
SetEnvIf Host second-store\.my-domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=second_store_code
SetEnvIf Host second-store\.my-domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

I've set up the subdomain to use the root Magento install as its base directory. Multistore works, I can change the themes, settings, products etc.

I've meticulously gone through everything seen here and more at least 5 times: [accepted answer has a category troubleshooting checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category)

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might cause the products to be available on the front end but not in category view? We're running Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2

**Edit: So far we've tried:**

1. The products are assigned to the proper category/store in Catalog.
2. The Products are Enabled. (we've tried batch enable/disable)
3. The products have a quantity.
4. The products are set to "In Stock"
5. Manage inventory os set to off
6. Display out of stock is set to yes.
7. Multi-website is being used and the products have been assigned to the target Website.
8. We've refreshed, deleted then disabled cache
9. We've reindexed all through admin and command line.
10. We've performed various var_dumps to check for proper store IDs
11. We've checked database group for USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN. it is 0 as it should be.
12. Products are aware of what store they're in and function as they should if you navigate directly to them.
13. We've run a database repair tool
14. We've run the database compare with fresh database tool. (this found two minor indexing issues) we reindexed again but with no luck.
15. We've disabled every non essential module with cache off.

We simply get a "There are no products matching the selection." error in category views.

**EDIT #2 These are the SQL Statements from the list.php troubleshooting that OSdave pointed out:**

I think it would also be advantageous to note that the default store isn't being used on the front end. It is simply a base we use to import products. The visible storefronts are seen in the .htaccess file above.

```
#Base store (1)(this works):
2013-10-03T14:12:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='3'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 10

#This is from the store2 store (MAGE_RUN_CODE=main-store_code):
2013-10-03T13:35:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=2 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='3'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.stock_id = 15 ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 10

#This is from the store3 store (RUN_CODE=second_store_code):
2013-10-03T14:48:05+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=3 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='37'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.stock_id = 1  ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 9
```

I'm looking into the differences. At first glance I've noticed the Website Ids may be off.

**EDIT #3**
I've compared all three queries and played with them a bit. What I've found is that it appears my catalog_product_index_price table appears to be missing 90% of my products and EVERY product that isn't store id=1

I can pull up any products with a store ID of 1 via an SQL query. Everything else fails. I've manually verified the values being passed. The products simply don't exist in the catalog_product_index_price table.

What now? I've tried database repair tools...

Edit #4
Stock_ID is coming from Multi-Warehouse an innoexts plugin we're using to manage shipping regions.

Comment: so you have a problem with reindexing: nothing in the logs about it? enable magento's developer mode and loggin and server's php errors display. As the Warehouse extension modifies the `catalog_product_index_price` table I guess it modifies the indexer also, so probably the problem comes from there: can you ask the author to correct it? As it is not a core functionality it is not really possible to help you without having the extension. To be sure, try to disable the extension, run the index and check if that solves the problem

Comment: have you tried to reindex with the extension disabled?

Comment: out of curiosity and interest to learn, if you could indicate what was the problem and how you solved it, that'd be great

Comment: Did you get a solution for this in the end? I too have followed all the steps in here and still cannot see the products in the category view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message "There are no products matching the selection." shows up if the product collection is empty:
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
```

As you see the product collection is retrieved by the method `getLoadedProductCollection()` which is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php` (if not overriden):

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    return $this->_getProductCollection();
}
```

In order to determine what is wrong, momentarily edit this file and add a log of the mysql query just before the return, i.e.:

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    Mage::log($this->_getProductCollection()->getSelect()->assemble(), null, 'product_collection.log', TRUE);
    return $this->_getProductCollection();
}
```

Load a category and go to `MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log/` and open the product_collection.log file. There you will see the mysql query executed.
I would then remove some parts of it, one by one, and run it against the db until I determine what causes the collection to be empty.

---

now that you have the mysql query, we can go on. There is one difference between the query that works (the first one) and the others: **AND price_index.stock_id = 1**
In a native EE 1.12, the `catalog_product_index_price` table does **NOT** have a `stock_id` column.
That makes me think that *someone* altered the code someway to add this: I'd look into to code to see where it comes from, and from there take actions to solve the bug

HTH

Comment: Working on this now, will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks, I finally feel Like i'm on the right track. I tried this last night but it was 2 am after an 18 hour troubleshooting session. I wasn't "all there" I think I've narrowed it down to rows missing from my catalog_product_index_price table (see OP edits). I'm not sure what to do next though?

Comment: @Bms85smb I've edited my answer with the next step I'd do if I were you. Indeed there is a problem with a db column.

Comment: @OSdave I have 4 store and single website, how can i display all products into store 1, for inventory I have created 4 stores, now i need to display all products into store 1, and also all store products available as it is appropriate stores.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your product assigned to the website you are viewing?
   Go to `Catalog > Manage Products` and edit a product.  Go to the `Websites` tab and ensure your product is a part of the website
2. Is the product a part of the Root Category, assigned to the store view?
   Go to `System > Manage Stores > [Click Store Name]` and check the `Root Category` dropdown.  Make sure your products are assigned to a child category of this Root Category.
3. Are your `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` variables being interpreted correctly?

`echo 'MAGE_RUN_CODE = ' . $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] . '<br />';`
`echo 'MAGE_RUN_TYPE = ' . $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'];`

See if the above returns the correct variable values for the URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. both 1 & 2 are a Yes. The third returns: "MAGE_RUN_CODE = second_store_code MAGE_RUN_TYPE = website". I'm viewing the second domain so this appears to be correct too.  The part that is really confusing to me is that if I comment out the htaccess code posted above. products show up in category view again for the main store.

Answer (score 0):

1. Temporarily turn off caching (if on at all).
2. Rule out the possibility of a theme based error - try falling back to the base default theme.
3. Check your website root category - go to System > Manage Stores > Click the store and check if it points to the right root category.
4. Run a full reindex via command line - First move to `[MAGENTO_ROOT]/shell/` and run `php indexer.php --reindexall`
5. Have you tried disabling all your extensions one by one? I'd say the most sure way to do this is to remove the xml file from `app/etc/modules/`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the Reply! Unfortunately We've tried all of these multiple times with multiple variations. I'm going to Edit the original post with a list of what we've tried.

Comment: @Bms85smb what about using the base default theme? I also added a 5th step

Comment: We've tried the base theme, Enterprise theme, a theme purchased from Theme Forest, and our existing theme. We've tried disabling a bunch of them but not all I'm going to try modules now.

Comment: I was able to remove ALL modules except for the required Mage modules. It did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might cause the products to be available on the front end but not in category view?

Your question is a bit confusing here. By "category view", did you mean Category Edit Form (admin panel) or Product Listing Page (frontend)?

If Product Listing Page, try to rebuild the URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Dave you rock, the sql query log saved me big time! So my problem was that when I moved the MySQL DB, the "NOT LOGGED IN" customer_group switched from customer_group_id 0 to 6. I changed it back to 0, re-index, re-cache and it worked. This 5 hour head-pounding nightmare is finally over...

For anyone else who had this mysql migration issue be sure to check each table as there's a few other places where 0 ID's get lost.