# Product not displaying in the category page in Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.8

All the features in my magento site is working fine,except the product listing in the category page.

I have enabled everything, tried clearing cache, product is marked in stock, quantity is > 0. But still its not working. But the product can be accessed directly, it is displayed while searching and in the list of recommended products.

I am using the theme Precise - magento.

Comment: have you try to run indexing process ? and it gives any error in listing page or any any log ?

Comment: Does 'is Anchor' is set to 'Yes' in the display settings of the particular category at manage categories??

Comment: @KeyurShah I have tried that no use

Comment: @PavanKumar Yes, it is already set as 'Yes'

Comment: Are the subcategories getting listed when you mouseover to the parent category? For ex: Can you see Cell Phones when you mouseover to Electronics?

Comment: Check category layout update at admin or in your theme. You can access product via searches so it might be something related to layout xml or layout update at admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checklist for whether items are in stock follows:

```
The products must be Visible in Catalog.
The products must be Enabled.
Product must have a stock Quantity.
The product must be set to In Stock.
If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
The product must be assigned to the target Category.
If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
```

You must refresh your Cache / Indexes, just to make sure.

Ref link: [Magento products will not show in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category)