# Magento 1.9 - Add category shows 1 product

Tags: magento, categories

Good day,
I have researched on this issue about Magento 1.9 not adding the category to the home page.
So, I ended up adding:

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="15" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

To the home page content. It also shows up on the home page BUT: only with 1 product out of a bunch (like 5). Why is that and can this be changed?

I am still very new to Magento and I haven't changed anything at the layout bit.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Ok, I discovered it only shows the most recently added item. That's all I know for now.

---

Edit 2: I have followed the steps from this post several times: [Magento products won't show in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category/2493774#2493774), but this also doesn't fix it.

Comment: first nee check how may is available on  cat 15.SO Just goto to it category page

Comment: I have 5 products with this categoy. Are there settings for displaying the amount of products in the category itself?