# Magento site migrated on another server

Tags: magento

I am using *magento version 1.9.0.1* and having site on this
Client asked me to migrate data to other server with same configuration
But when I transferred all data to another server everything is working
fine except products not showing up at front-end.It shows in database and admin side. 
I guess this in **list.phtml**

```
$products = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

is not working

And I have also checked with loading base theme magento but no luck in that.

If anyone help me in this would be really helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: clear your cache and temp tables and perform reindex

Comment: I did indexing using admin panel as well as by code but no luck and did clear cache also.

Comment: had you clear temp tables?

Comment: You mean all tmp tables or only catalog_category_tmp?

Comment: log_url,log_url_info

Comment: Should I clear both?Contains large data

Comment: yeap, don't worry this is temporarily data

Comment: I cleared both but still no luck

Comment: have you check quantity of products and check for out of stock?

Comment: I created test catgory and put one test product under that but that also not showing up

Comment: Yes I have imported all live site data as it is those products are in stock in live site

Comment: have a look http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/magento-store-after-migration

Comment: I looked and verify all steps everything seems to be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts finally found solution,it was because of license issue 
which is only for domain and i was accessing it from other IP and when I pointed it to that domain all things started working fine.

Thank you all for your inputs and help

Answer (score 1):

You can do following steps :

1) go to backend, select all products, click on update attributes, click on websites on left, check your website and click on submit.

2) Go to system->config catalog and check if you have disabled retrieval of out of stock products on listing page.

3) After above steps, reindex your products and inventory.

4) Delete magento/var/cache/*  and check website again.

Comment: Thanks but I tried above steps which you mentioned but still not able to see products

Comment: Categories are coming up but not able to see products

Comment: Is your website a multistore on or single store?

Comment: Also i found below thread with similar issue, you can try and update here is it works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493141/magento-products-will-not-show-in-category

Comment: Products are showing there when I am searching in search bar but still not able to see them in respective categories

Comment: If this is the case then please check product visibility. It has to be catalog-search to be able to view products both on catalog and search result page. If it is only search, products will only be visible on search result page.